# How to set the border color of a cell in DataGrip

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

As shown in the image below, the border color of a cell is yellow and I want to change it. Even though I googled it many times, I still can't find the settings to change.

[image]

The official documentation mentions that there is a place to set the color.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/database-color-settings-dialog.html

> Database Explorer), right-click any object (for example, a table or a data source) and select Tools | Set Color

But after I changed the setting, it seems that I can only change the background color of the background color of the display window, not the border color of the cells.

The version of DataGrip I am using is `2023.1.2`.

Answer (score 3):

This color is determined by *Indent guide* in settings **Editor | Color Scheme | General** (see screenshot)

But it's not documented and very difficult to find. I created an issue about it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-18220/Add-grid-cell-border-color-to-Editor-Color-Scheme-Data-Editor-and-Viewer-settings-page please upvote

[image: DataGrip settings page to change border color of cells]